# MongoDB find nested queries to populate object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm building a node.js application with mongoose, but I'm currently stuck with me trying to query the MongoDB properly...

I have currently 3 MongoDB models:

```
Room: {_id, name}
Row: {_id, roomid, name}
Seat: {_id rowid, position, number, status}
```

1 room has many rows, 1 row has many seats.

I am able to fetch a Room object with all rows with following query:

```
Room.findOne({ name: req.params.room_name }, { __v: 0 })
  .then(room => {
    room = room.toObject();
    Row.find({ room: new ObjectId(room._id) }, { room: 0, __v: 0 })
      .sort({ name: 1 })
      .then(rows => {
        // current code, not working
        // rows.foreach(row => {
        //   row = row.toObject();
        //   Seat.find({row: new OBjectId(row._id)})
        //     .sort({position: 1})
        //     .then(seats => {
        //       row.seats = seats;
        //     })
        //     .catch(err => console.log(err));
        res.json(room);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  });
```

However, I cannot find the solution to fetch the seats for every row, the async processing is killing my logic on every try.
Ive tried just a for loop, async.waterfall(), Promise.all(), but I fail every single time.

Anyone bother to help me out? Thanks!

**Remark:** As proposed in the comments and possible answers, I should work with only one model, I had that already but I was having issues with updating multiple seats. Will look further into that.

Comment: Row.find({ room: new ObjectId(room._id) } -> room did not match your Row: {roomid, name}. it schoud be roomid. Same with your Seats

Comment: Fixed my models in the description. As stated, room with rows is working at the moment, adding the seats to the rows isn't...

Comment: *"I have currently 3 MongoDB models:"* - In all honesty this is not the intended use case for MongoDB. You are designing for an RDBMS and MongoDB is not an RDBMS. You should either rethink how to model based on a "document oriented approach" or if it fits an RDBMS then just use that. MongoDB *"sort of"* supports joins, but the usage is for the "edge cases" where most of your primary design was modeled differently. You appear to be thinking fully relationally here, and that makes this a bad fit.

Comment: I am surprised async await is not working, Are you making your primary method async? 
Also you should break your calls into sub methods and each method should be defined as async await.

Comment: @Sohan I can take a look into this, but as stated by Neil Lunn, I will go for the better document oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this fairly more easily by properly setting the references `ref` and slightly modifying your models. However, I will modify your code to show you how I would do it following your approach, and then I will provide an example with mongoose population on referenced fields:

## Your approach with a plain schema

Before getting into the code, I will substitute the `.toObject()` call on the documents by `.lean()`, which is a mongoose method that does that for you after querying documents and optimizes the query because it skips the process of converting the MongoDB raw documents to Mongoose objects:

```
// Encapsulate this with try-catch
const room = await Room.findOne({ name: req.params.room_name }, { __v: 0 }).lean().exec()
const rows = await Row.find({ roomid: room._id }, { roomid: 0, __v: 0 }).lean().exec()

// This is a blocking loop
for (let row of rows) {
    const seats = await Seat.find({ rowid: row._id }, { rowid:0, __v: 0 }).lean().exec()
    row.seats = seats
}

room.rows = rows
res.json(room)
// Close try-catch
```

Now the for-loop can be optimized a little by using `Promise.all()`, which will execute every loop iteration asynchronously:

```
await Promises.all(rows.map(async (row) => {
    const seats = await Seat.find({ rowid: row._id }, { rowid:0, __v: 0 }).lean().exec()
    row.seats = seats
})
```

## Mongoose population approach

Let's redefine a little bit your models by just following the reasoning that naturally came to you in a straight forward way:

> 1 room has many rows

Then you could expect your room to have an array of row IDs, as follows:

#### Room.model

```
const roomModel = mongoose.model('Room', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rows: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Row'
    }]
))
```

Further on,

> 1 row has many seats

#### Row.model

```
const rowModel = mongoose.model('Row', new mongoose.Schema({
    seats: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Seat'
    }],
    name: String
))
```

And finally your seat model would be as simple as:

#### Seat.model

```
const seatModel = mongoose.model('Seat', new mongoose.Schema({
    position: Number,
    number: Number
))
```

Now the query is **much simpler**:

```
const room = await Room.findOne({ name: req.params.room_name }, { __v: 0 })
    .populate({
        path: 'rows',
        select: '-__v', // Remove __v field
        populate: {
            path: 'seats',
            select: '-__v' // Remove __v field
    }).lean().exec()

res.json(room)
```

As you can see, it is **way more simple** following this approach and correctly designing your data models. **However**, this is not yet the way you would expect to design the data models in MongoDB, as stated by [Neill Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973361/mongodb-find-nested-queries-to-populate-object#comment96707662_54973361) in the comments. Instead of defining 3 simple data models as you did, it would be better to define only 1 model with arrays of embedded subdocuments for the rows and seats schemas. Something similar to this:

#### Room.model

```
mongoose.model('Room', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rows: [{
        name: String,
        seats: [{
            position: Number,
            number: Number,
    }]
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Although I have to say that I ahve the 1-document way already in place, but then I was stuck in altering seat properties (seat also have the status property). That caused me to think: what if I split the models so I can query every single seat object, which is indeed more a relation approach... Updating my initial post as well to make this clear